# Controls on flash video don't work in IE8

Tags: html, flash, video, mediaelement.js

So as the title says, this is what's bothering me.

I'm implementing mediaelement.js library for better Android support, and this is my 
    head element code for that library right here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelementplayer.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mediaelement.js"></script>
```

and this is my video code:

```
    <video width="640" height="360" controls>
<!-- videos with different format types --> 
        <source src="explore_promo.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="explore_promo.webm"  type="video/webm" />
        <source src="explore_promo.ogv"  type="video/ogg" />
<!-- flash fallback code for ie8 -->        
        <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"    data="flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;file=explore_promo.mp4" />
        </object>
    </video>
```

Now, all browsers render video element just fine. The problem occurs when I test this code in IE8. The video starts to play by itself even though the autoplay is not enabled and I've set the controlbar value inside my  element, but it does not show any controls (play, pause etc.), and also it loops all the time. I would like to have video controls in IE8 so the users can play / pause any time they want - without looping and autoplaying.

Comment: Does this jsfiddle.net/fxf2hm7z/show/ work on IE8?

Comment: It does work, but only as a download link for video.